# Does google map load limit not apply if loaded through iframe?

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

Id like to include a map in every products checkout page. I have read earlier today that I do not need to include my key if I intend to load google maps through an iframe. If thats the case, does that mean I can load the map infinitely onto my page without being billed when hitting the usage limit of 2500 map loads?

I am still confused about this.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide):

> There are no usage limits for the Maps Embed API. You can embed maps
>   or Street View panoramas on your high-traffic websites without fear of
>   hitting a usage cap or query-per-second throttling.

Comment: Brilliant! So I may add a map to display store locations with a pointer for free through google maps ? :O wow

Then what exactly does this usage apply to? like what functionality are we talking about here? can you link me with an example on a live website?

Comment: The usage of the Google Maps Embed API (basically, using an iframe) has no limitations, but the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) has a limit.
I don't have an example on hand but as soon as you are not using Google Maps via the iframe but via the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) you might be charged at some point.